# How to downgrade rspec 3.0.0 to rspec 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have an issue with running the rake program on Test-First Teaching with rspec 3.0.0. It says "Could not find ''rspec (~) 2) - did find: [rspec-3.0.0]" I have a feeling this means I should download an older version of rspec to run the program. However, when I tried to download the 3 most recent versions of rspec 2 (2.99.0, 2.14.1 & 2.14.0) it always says "ERROR: could not find a valid gem ... in any repository"

Please help! I am using Windows 7 and would really like to get through this material

Comment: have a look in your Gemfile ... what is in the section that is labeled "group :test" ? If there isn't one, do a search in the Gemfile for the word "rspec" and see what it says

Comment: It doesn't have a section called group :test, it just says this "source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "rake"
gem "rspec", ">=2.0""

Comment: right... so no `rspec-rails` gem then?

Comment: also  comment code-formatting is awful. Can yo please copy your Gemfile into your question and format it nicely so it's easy to read for others too? :)

Comment: I seemed to have resolved my issue, I needed to initialize the rspec in the project directory. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Hey no probs. Please write up your solution and add it as an "answer". Don't forget that other people might have the same problem as you, and could benefit from what you learned in solving the issue (it's part of how you pay back the community for helping you out).